# Motivation behind Definition of Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

How Riemann came to definition of integral?What was the motivation behind the definition?

Comment: The motivation is to define and calculate the surface area under a given curve

Comment: Approximating the area under the curve using a Riemann sum seems like a natural idea, at least. So somehow we want to make precise the idea that a number $L$ is the limit of Riemann sums. So, let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that...

Comment: See [Integral: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#History) for a brief overview.